# Why can't you buy water for ma'aser sheni?

Tags: water, maaser-tithes, schach, masechet-sukkah, tractate-maaser-sheini

[Ma'aser Sheni 1:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maaser_Sheni.1.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says that water is an invalid option for buying with ma'aser sheni money. The reason, as Bartenura's commentary explains, is because ma'aser sheni money can only be used to buy things that grow from the ground.

However, the sechach (roof) of a sukka also has to be made with things that grow from the ground. This is learned (according to one opinion) from the verse that describes a cloud of mist that rises from the earth ([Genesis 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0)). Just as a cloud grows from the ground, so too a sukka has to be made with a substance that grows from the ground ([Sukka 11b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.11b.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)).

If water is considered a substance that grows from the ground for the purpose of building a sukka (even as the prototypical case), why is it invalid as an option to buy for ma'aser sheni for the very reason that it doesn't grow from the ground?

Comment: Water is mekabel tumea

Comment: If water is giddulei Karka then collecting rain water on Shabbat should be Meamer (among other possible Shabbat Nafka Minah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the deepness of the question. But the Rash quotes the Gemara Eruvin 27b in which the exclusion of water and salt for maaser sheni is learned from drashot. One of them is cited by the Rash, Klal Ufrat Uchlal. For maaser sheni the necessary conditions are not only gidule Karka, but Peri Miperi Ugidule Karka or, following another explanation, a Vlad mivlad ugidule karka. From both water is excluded, because it grows from the ground (gidule Karka), but it doesn't grow from something else that grows from the ground (peri miperi or vlad mivlad).

> 12. והני תנאי דרשי כללי ופרטי דתניא ונתתה הכסף בכל אשר תאוה נפשך כלל
> 13. בבקר ובצאן וביין ובשכר פרט
> 14. ובכל אשר תשאלך נפשך חזר וכלל
> 15. כלל ופרט וכלל אי אתה דן אלא כעין הפרט **ומה הפרט מפורש פרי מפרי וגידולי קרקע אף כל פרי מפרי וגידולי קרקע**
>       We need a fruit coming from a fruit, that is growing from the earth.
> 16. ותניא אידך מה הפרט מפורש **ולד ולדות הארץ אף כל ולד ולדות הארץ** מאי בינייהו אמר אביי דגים איכא בינייהו למאן דאמר פרי מפרי וגידולי קרקע הני דגים גידולי קרקע נינהו למאן דאמר ולד ולדות הארץ דגים ממיא איברו
>       We need a "born from a born" that is growing from the earth.
> 17. ותניא אידך מה הפרט מפורש **ולד ולדות הארץ אף כל ולד ולדות הארץ**

Comment: I edited the answer for clarity. If I understood something incorrectly or differently than you did, you can change it back